# Docker-compose (and django): Can't get environment variables onto the services

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm trying to write a small docker(-compose) deployment solution for a small Django application.

Currently, the django-compose file, named `docker-compose.dev.yaml` looks something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - dev.env
```

The file `dev.env` looks like this:

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY=We9ZyuSKsP9Mgvsrt74gExF8baWbGL # not important that this leaks
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost
```

However, when django tries to start, I get the following:

> #11 0.634     ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(" ")
>
> #11 0.634 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Basically, the environment variable is returning `None`, meaning the variables aren't getting onto the container.

I tried, [according to the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers), to do this:

```
    # ...
    environment:
      - DEBUG
      - SECRET_KEY
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS
```

Without any luck.

Any ideas? [The repository behind the code](https://github.com/ruilvo/radioamadorismo-website/tree/1d4cd60ad7f3468e3bc16ab193603f90fad1a896) is public, I invite you to try.

My current test environment is Docker desktop on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I figured it out.

Turns out that this line in the `Dockerfile` for the backend:

```
RUN python manage.py migrate
```

Was the problem. I didn't realize it ran at build time, not at runtime, so the environment variables weren't available.

I moved into a script called at runtime and not it all works!

`backend/Dockerfile`:

```
# ...
# Make files executable
RUN chmod +x start.dev.sh
```

`backend/start.dev.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And `./docker-compose.dev.yaml`:

```
# ...
    command: ./start.dev.sh
# ...
```